# Error while creating git branch - Offset and length were out of bounds for the array

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I am trying to create git branch from master using Visual Studio 2017.

Getting below error:

Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Already tried solution as suggested in [git - Create Branch From Tag Error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/347771/git-create-branch-from-tag-error.html) to close all VS/Team Explorer instances, and clean cache folder C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache. Then try again.

No luck with the suggested solution, looking for help/guidance to resolve

[image: Offset and length error]

Comment: I'm seeing the identical problem. Just did a check-in into my master branch and tried to create a branch point... failed with the same error. Is there a limit to the number of branches altogether?